# How to get all possible return values of a python function?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a python function defined as such :

```py
def my_function():
    if foo:
        return "a string"
    else:
        if bar:
            return "another string"
        else:
            return 123456789
```

with `foo` and `bar` global variables, defined outside the scope of that function. How can I get all possible return values of that function, i.e. get the list (or tuple) `["a string", "another string", 123456789]`.

I tried looking at the `inspect` module as well as the `ast` module of Python's standard library, but none of the functions there seem to be of any help.

Comment: Your code is a simple example, but there is no way to determine all possible return values in a general fashion. How do you get all possible return values for, say, `return random.random()`? What about impossible return values (e.g. `if 1 == 2: return "Foo"`)?

Comment: You could pull constants out of `return` statements with a simple parser.  However, if you want a generalized solution to "all possible return values", that's not possible.  For one thing, that's equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: This is not possible to predetermine, given the dynamic nature of python you cannot even determine the type let alone all possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by no means a general solution, but if your function uses only constants as return values (and **only** as return values), you can use this:

```
>>> my_function.__code__.co_consts
(None, 'a string', 'another string', 123456789)
```

`co_consts` contains **constants** used in the bytecode (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)). It will return all constants (and not just return values).

Chances are this is not what you're looking for, so be very careful. This will never generalize since some functions use external state, randomness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this would be somewhat similar to what you're trying to do:

```
def my_function():
    output_values = ["a string", "another string", 123456789]
    if foo:
        return output_values[0]
    else:
        if bar:
            return output_values[1]
        else:
            return output_values[2]

    return output_values
```